# Angular controller(delete) with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am new Angular and Laravel and I would like to ask you about delete function.

At the moment I got an message obj is not an object)
How can I remove this bug and delete user?

---

AngularJS controller

```
app.controller('userListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Users',
function ($scope, Users) {
    $scope.users = Users.query();
$scope.destroy = function(id){
    console.log(id);
    Users.remove(id);   
}

}]);
```

Service

```
app.factory('Users', function($resource) {
return $resource('/api/users/:userID'); // Note the full endpoint      address
});
```

HTML

```
<h1>User List</h1>
    <div class="span12 baseBox">
        <table class="span11"></br>
        {{successMsg}}
        <tr>
            <th class="mytable" >UserID</th>
            <th class="mytable" >Username</th>
            <th class="mytable" >Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td class="mytable">{{user.id}}</td>
            <td class="mytable">{{user.username}}</td>
            <td class="mytable"><button class="btn-danger" ng-click="destroy(user.id)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Laravel-

Controller

```
<?php
 public function destroy($id)
   {
    $delete = UserRegModel::destroy($id);

    if($delete){
        return Response::json(array('success'=>true));
    }
    else{
        return 'error';
    }
}


Routes

Route::group(array('prefix'=>'/api'), function(){
Route::resource('users','UserController');
//Route::post('/','myController@postRegUser');
});

 ?>
```

Comment: Where you get the error "obj is not an object" in PHP or in JS?

Comment: Hi Pathik Gandhi I found this error in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your resource configuration is not complete. You need to add the paramDefaults to your $resource definition:

```
app.factory('Users', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:userID', {userID: '@id'});
});
```

Then in your destroy function you can use:

```
 Users.remove({userID:id});
```

Alternatively, when you use the query function in the $resource service, each of the objects in the returned array will be have instance methods allowing you to run restful operations on the individual objects. So you can pass the full user object through to your destroy function. You should be able to do:

```
$scope.destroy = function(user){
   user.$remove(); 
}
```